# Messages table in MySQL, getting last message for each thread

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to get the last message from each conversation, the only problem is I am not using a conversations table.

I am using one messages table, my table columns looks like this:

```
id  from_id     to_id   text    isread  isseen  created_at  updated_at
```

Right now I am able to retrieve conversations like this:

```
$messages = Message::select('*')->
                from(DB::raw("(select * from `messages` where `to_id` = ".Auth::id()." order by `created_at` desc) as sub"))->
                groupBy('from_id')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->
                paginate(7);
```

The only downside to this is I am not retrieving the last message for each conversation, I am retrieving the last message received.

How can I retrieve the last message of each conversation?

Example Retrieve user63 conversations and last message for each conversation:

```
id  from_id     to_id   text    isread  isseen  created_at  updated_at 
23  224         63      a        0         0    2015-03-28 22:23:54     2015-03-28 22:23:54
20  63          225     b        0        0     2015-03-28 22:23:06     2015-03-28 22:23:06
16  225         63      hi       0        1     2015-03-28 22:21:32     2015-03-28 22:21:32
```

I thought of an idea, not sure though:

```
$messages = Message::select('*')->
            from(DB::raw("
(
(select *, to_id as theuser from `messages` where `to_id` = ".Auth::id()." order by `created_at` desc)
union
(select *, from_id as theuser from `messages` where `from_id` = ".Auth::id()." order by `created_at` desc) group by theuser
) as sub"))->
            groupBy('from_id')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->
            paginate(7);
```

Comment: Add a constraint with the `from_id`?

Comment: you mean where to_id or where from_id? I will be getting duplicate threads.

Comment: where `from_id` (this is based on assuming by conversation you are meaning the messages between just two people.

Comment: yeah, it's just two people, but again, how will I have unique threads... consider this for example: from_id 50 to id 60, and from_id 60 to_id 50 how will you get the last message for that thread assuming you don't know about 60, you're getting 50's threads.

Comment: If it's a conversation thread, you'd have to know about both parties... unless I'm missing something else.

Comment: I am retrieving all threads of a specific user, and need to get the last message for each thread, not the last message of a specific thread.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74002/discussion-between-guy-mazuz-and-jon).

Comment: You may compare created_at time to get last massage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution myself, thanks everyone! :)

```
$messages = Message::select('*')->
from(DB::raw("
    ( 
      SELECT *,`from_id` as `theuser`
      FROM `messages` WHERE `to_id` = 63
      union
      SELECT *,`to_id` as `theuser`
      FROM `messages` WHERE `from_id` = 63
      order by `created_at` desc
    ) as `sub`"))->groupBy('theuser')->
                   orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->
                   paginate(7);
```

Comment: This code is totally unreadable, I suggest you to pay more attention to coding style, https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md

Answer (score 2):

This must works too:
The difference in this approach is a self join with a little help from max() function like this:

```
SELECT from_id, MAX(created_at) AS last FROM messages GROUP BY from_id
```

So:

```
$pagedMessages = Message::select('*')->
  from(
    DB::raw("
        messages AS m 
        JOIN (
            SELECT from_id, MAX(created_at) AS lm FROM messages GROUP BY from_id
        ) AS lm 
        ON lm.from_id = m.from_id AND lm.created_at = m.created_at 
    "))->
paginate(7);
```