# JPA query get last message for each interlocutor

Tags: sql, jpa, select, hql, message

I have table `messages` with `id, sender_id, receiver_id, sent_time, message`, how it's possible to select last message for each interlocutor if I have user_id, which can be sender and/or receiver? I've found [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29321354/messages-table-in-mysql-getting-last-message-for-each-thread) for usual MySQL query, but that will not work with JPA query/CriteriaQuery.
In MySQL query looks like this:

```
SELECT mm.* FROM messages mm
JOIN
(SELECT MAX(m.sent),u.id, m.id as idd FROM messages m
JOIN users u ON (m.sender_id=u.id OR m.receiver_id=u.id)
WHERE (m.sender_id=:uid AND m.receiver_id=u.id) OR (m.receiver_id=:uid AND m.sender_id=u.id) OR (m.receiver_id=:uid AND m.sender_id=:uid)
GROUP BY u.id) p2 ON mm.id=p2.idd
```

How to write this query ("join select max(m.sent), u.id..." this part) in HQL or CriteriaQuery?